# Flex runtime/flash player/Brownser relationship

Tags: flash, apache-flex, browser

I want to check on the flex runtime related to brownser. If have one brownser with different tabs, in each tab, a flex application is opened. In this case, how the work flow, are they using one flash player but different VM, and in each tab, flex talk with each brownser tab and from tab talk to flash player or how the communication goes?

Comment: there is not realy a such thing as a "Flex" Runtime.  Flex Applications can run in the browser based Flash Player; or the Adobe AIR Desktop/mobile runtime.  That said; i don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

in a browser, they use one of the installed Flash Player. In IE its the ActiveX, in Chrome it is Pepper, and in other places the Netscape Flash Player Plugin by default. One Flash Player instance is running for all Flash objects (two, if you have IE and Chrome displaying Flash as well), and they are sharing the process. This means if your swf is using 100% CPU in a tab, youtube will be slow. But if you use workers, a flash object can have more threads, meaning it can use more cpu cores. different swf's cant communicate with eachother. Flash has a timer, ticking at 60 FPS, and every Flash has a framerate, 24FPS by default. On every tick, it checks which Flashes should step a frame, and steps a frame for them, throws events, etc.
Cheers